# Selecting a letter from random group of array for registered user in php

Tags: php, arrays, random

The problem is I have two groups say A and B which I have predefined in an array like

```
$random_groups = [B,A,A,B,A,A,B,B,A,A,B,B,B,A,A,B,A,B,B,A,A,A,B,B,A,B,B,B,A,A,A,B,B,A,B,A,A,B,B,B,A,A,A,B,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,B,B,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,B,A,B,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,B,B,A,A,B,A,B,A...]
```

and when user submits a form he should get B from the above array if he is the first person to register after I apply this logic and if second person registers he should get A, if third he should get A and so on.

I am so confused to have to work around this logic. I tried a few options but didn't got the result properly.

Comment: Why not just randomly choose between A or B? https://3v4l.org/saDVc

Comment: That's too broad to answer. I'll give you an overview on how you can approach this. Get the user id after `insert` into db, and then `$random_groups[$user_id];`.

Comment: What happens when your user base exceeds the number of elements in the array?

Comment: Voting to close this question because raveena is unresponsive and also this question won't help future readers.

Comment: I can't chose it randomly because we have certain statics logic applied from user to choose between A and B those are groups

Comment: @LawrenceCherone if the number exceeds then it would again start from he beginning of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<?php
    $random_groups = array('B','A','A','B','B','A','A','B','A','B','B','A','A','B','A','A','B','B','A','B','A','B','B','A','A','B','A','B','B','A','B',
                      'A','B','A','B','A','A','B','A','B','B','A','A','B','A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B',
                      'B','A','A','B','A','B','B','A','A','A','B','B','A'); //IF THOSE ARE STRINGS YOU SHOULD ADD quotations (YOUR PATTERN)
    $rank_reg = 201; //EXAMPLE IF HE IS 201 REGISTERED

    do{
        array_push($random_groups,'B','A','A','B','B','A','A','B','A','B','B','A','A','B','A','A','B','B','A','B','A','B','B','A','A','B','A','B','B','A','B',
                      'A','B','A','B','A','A','B','A','B','B','A','A','B','A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B',
                      'B','A','A','B','A','B','B','A','A','A','B','B','A');
        }while($rank_reg -1 > count($random_groups)); // THIS CODE WILL ADD YOUR PATTERN TO THE END OF THE ARRAY WHILE THE RANK EXCEEDS THE INDEX OF YOUR ARRAY
       
    foreach($random_groups as $index => $output):
       if(($rank_reg - 1) == $index): // ADDED A COMPUTATION OF -1 BECAUSE ARRAYS STARTS AT 0
        echo $output;
       endif;
        continue; //IF RANK IS NOT MATCH TO AVAILABLE GROUPS
    endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: *YOUR ARRAY IS WRONG THIS IS WHAT YOUR ARRAY SHOULD LOOK LIKE* Nope. Did you tried executing it?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat i did though, it wasn't string so it will throw `undefined ` error

Comment: But it's not wrong. `A` and `B` might be constants.

Comment: @jerome nice job! i run the snippet and gives me correct output i have to manually change the $rank_reg to increase from 1,2,3,.... . So i have to look at the solution for that to increase the userid from table.

Comment: @raveenasurani if it solve your problem mark it as answer, if not tell me so i can improve thanks

Comment: Sure @jerome i am working on it right now! if i get successful i'll sure give a thumbs up :D

Comment: @jerome i have two problems : 1) my ID in table is starting from 606 so this logic is not working with that. 2) i have 200 random A & B in array so what after 200 users get register would this logic work?

Comment: @raveenasurani my concern is why do you choose in array between A&B rather than assigning random A&B. Because if you do this method it will allocate alot of time/memory

Comment: @jerome because its a result of statistics calculation and i have to use this instead of using rand A & B

Comment: As i notice your pattern is always B,A,A,B is that correct ?

Comment: no the whole patteren is different this was an example

Comment: the pattern is as follows : 'B','A','A','B','B','A','A','B','A','B','B','A','A','B','A','A','B','B','A','B','A','B','B','A','A','B','A','B','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','A','B','A','B','B','A','A','B','A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B','B','A','A','B','A','B','B','A','A','A','B','B','A'

Comment: and still more uptill 200 elements

Comment: @jerome same question but what if data are stored in database in tables and the table has ID and passcode as field and there are total 150 records in that table and every user should be given ID/Code uptill 150 user registration and again starting from first id for 151th user